# Circular progress indicator without white background

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-circularprogressindicator

I'm new to the flutter world and I would like to know how to remove this white background from the circular progress indicator of flutter. Below I will leave a screenshot and my code.

[image: SCREEN]

Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void showLoading(BuildContext context, {required String text}) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (_) {
      return SimpleDialog(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(text, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}

void hideLoading(BuildContext context) {
  if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with circular progress indicator and instead has to do with the dialog (either with `SimpleDialog` class or with `showDialog` function) I advice you look for settings on both of those instead, alternatively, you can also use [Stack widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer helps you, you need to change the background color under `SimpleDialog`

```
void showLoading(BuildContext context, String text) {
showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (_) {
    return SimpleDialog(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,//here set the color to transparent
      elevation: 0,
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(text, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
 }
```

Comment: add  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
             showDialog(
                context: context,
                barrierDismissible: false,
                builder: (_) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CircularProgressIndicator(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text(text, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
```